# Постановка тире на месте ожидаемого двоеточия

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, тире-или-двоеточие

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти правило (ссылку), согласно которому тире можно поставить на месте двоеточия (если их уже несколько в предложении), чтобы улучшить восприятие.
Например:
**Что легче: сказать обидчику: ты сам такой и сякой, или сказать: прости, может быть, я ещё хуже, чем ты говоришь?**

Здесь можно бы поставить тире:
**Что легче — сказать обидчику: ты сам такой и сякой, или сказать: прости, может быть, я ещё хуже, чем ты говоришь?**

Answer (score 1):

**Что** легче — сказать обидчику "**ты сам такой и сякой**" или сказать  "**прости, может быть, я ещё хуже, чем ты говоришь**"?

Структура предложения: Что легче — сказать (1) или сказать (2).

1) С помощью тире обособляем пояснительную конструкцию, которая раскрывает содержание местоимения ЧТО. Тире ставится, если ударение падает на местоимение (оно более предпочтительно). Но двоеточие тоже возможно.

2) Дословное высказывание (прямая речь) оформлено в виде однородных дополнений, связанных союзом ИЛИ.